# query-replace within LaTeX/Math

Tags: latex, auctex, debugging, query-replace

The answer below was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44913296.
This is the most upvoted answer there.

Unfortunately, after running the code (for example by replacing q with \theta) one encounters the following error:

`match-substitute-replacement: Invalid use of ‘\’ in replacement text`

Moreover, if I use `\\theta` instead of `\theta`, query-replace does not work properly, it looks outside LaTeX formula as well.

Is there a way to correct the code?

```
  (defun latex-replace-in-math ()
    "Call `query-replace-regexp' with `isearch-filter-predicate' set to filter out matches outside LaTeX math environments."
    (interactive)
    (let ((isearch-filter-predicate
     (lambda (BEG END)
       (save-excursion (save-match-data (goto-char BEG) (texmathp)))))
    (case-fold-search nil))
    (call-interactively 'query-replace-regexp)))
```

Comment: This works as expected for me: if I replace `q` with `\\theta`, only `q` characters inside math environments get replaced, and are replaced by `\theta`. This is with Emacs 28.0.50

Comment: @Tyler Can you test also with a document with q outside math environments?

Comment: Works also for me with Emacs 27.1 and AUCTeX 13.0.4 with the following example document `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
q

\(q\)
\end{document}`

Comment: @name I did, and it worked. q replaced inside math environment, but not outside.